# Normalization - Migrate Data to Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization

I have a table `template` with the field `json`. Since `json` can be the same for many `template` (1:n) I created another table `template_json` and added the field `template_json_id` (FK) to `template`.

To migrate all data from one table to antoher I used following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO db.template_json (`json`)
SELECT `json`
FROM db.template;
```

This migrates the data perfectly, but of course leaves my `template.template_json_id` empty. I would need to update each row's `template.template_json_id` (FK) with `template_json.id` from the insert.

Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: do you have duplicates?

Comment: alot of the json is duplicate, yes

Comment: have you added an auto increment primary key to the template_json table?

Comment: Yes, `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have duplicate  you can  use and update with inner join

```
update template
inner join template on template_json.json = template.json
set template.template_json_id = template_json.id;
```

if you have duplicate you should  populate with a select distinct

```
INSERT INTO db.template_json (`json`)
SELECT distinct `json`
FROM db.template;
```

Comment: This would probably do it for the migration. json actually has duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is going to be a multi step process. You have already created the new table and populated, it. The next step is to eliminate duplicates. There are lot's of different ways to do this, one that comes to my mind is:

```
DELETE FROM template_json WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM template_json GROUP BY json HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as A);
```

This could be very slow. The next step is to update the existing table.

```
UPDATE template
INNER JOIN template_json on template_json.json = template.json
SET template.template_json_id = template_json.id;
```

This too could be rather slow. An index on the json column might help. Finally, after taking a backup.

```
ALTER TABLE template DROP COLUMN json;
```